# consequences of `sudo rm` apps that shipped with the OS (like Photos, Messages, Mail)

Tags: development, macos

I've got numerous OSes installed on my Macintosh laptop for certain reasons. So I'd like to be as lightweight in my OS X as possible. What are the consequences of `sudo rm -rf`'ing  the following application that are allegedly unmodifiable/deletable because *it’s required by OS X*?

I am not a photographer so I don't really need

```
Photos.app Maps.app "Image Capture.app" "Photo Booth.app"
```

For communication I use emails mainly and I much prefer mutt so I'd like to get rid of

```
Mail.app Messages.app Contacts.app
```

I use vim mainly (and atom & Xcode occasionally) so I'd also like to get rid of

```
TextEdit.app Notes.app "Utilities/Script Editor.app"
```

I also don't see myself ever using

```
Calculator.app Calendar.app Dashboard.app "DVD player.app" "Game Center.app" 
iBooks.app Reminders.app Stickies.app "Time Machine.app"
```

These are what I use OS X mainly for

1. iOS development (sometimes)
2. Web development: mainly to test browser compatibility
3. Updating the firmware

So would I break anything important if I delete all the applications mentioned above?

Comment: The applications you've listed use about 200 MB in /Applications, so it's probably not worth the trouble anyway.

Comment: Glad to discover a mutt user on Mac OS X ;). Great professional tool!

Comment: You don't risk anything removing the exact applications you indicated. Be warned Apple Update will restore them unless you let impossible to remove empty files with the expected name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect deleting the applications from the "/Applications" folder to break anything for you. Mostly because any part of these applications that is used by other applications will be stored in other locations like the "/Library" or "/System/Library" folder.

Having said this, I don't see any real benefit to deleting these applications. When Apple release an update for the operating system there is a good chance that it will restore a good portion of the files that you've deleted.

If you aren't using these applications the only benefit I can see to deleting these files is getting you back a little bit of hard drive space. I would recommend not deleting them from "/Applications", and just in case, I would **STRONGLY** recommend against deleting anything from the "/Library" or "/System/Library" folders.